# RUnit does not stop docker-compose's containers

Tags: docker, runit, docker-compose

I would like to have a RUnit service to supervise a set of containers launched by `docker-compose` tool, here's my the runit script:

In `/etc/sv/app/run`

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2>&1

APP_HOME=/home/myapp

source $APP_HOME/env.sh
exec docker-compose -f $APP_HOME/docker-compose.yml up
```

Here's what I have then:

- `sv start app` - launches the docker-compose thing just fine
- `sv stop app`  - stops docker-compose process itself **but for unknown reason it leaves the containers running**

Is there any chance to have the `stop` command to stop containers as well? I thought that is what docker-compose should do when it gets stopped by RUnit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with docker (yet) but I have familiarity with runit.

When you issue `sv stop app` you are actually telling `runsvdir` to signal the `runsv` for your docker launch to tear down the process.  If you need something to signal the container to shut down, it won't happen because `runsv` will haul off and kill any child processes that are attached.  You may wish to read up on `./finish` scripts, which are tasked with cleaning up things.